# I am passing in data from MongoDB via an API (which works). to visualise But I keep getting this TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

This is my LevyChart.jsx file

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { useGetLevyQuery } from "../state/api";

const LevyChart = ({ isDashboard = false, view }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetLevyQuery();

  const [levyLine, nameLine] = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return [];

    const { quarters } = data;
    const levyLine = {
      id: "levy",
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      data: [],
    };
    const nameLine = {
      id: "name",
      color: theme.palette.secondary[600],
      data: [],
    };

    console.log("quarters", quarters);
    Object.values(quarters).reduce(
      (acc, { year, name, levy }) => {
        const curLevy = acc.levy + levy;
        const curName = acc.name + name;
    
        levyLine.data = [
          ...levyLine.data,
          { x: year, y: curLevy },
        ];
        nameLine.data = [
          ...nameLine.data,
          { x: year, y: curName },
        ];
    
        return { levy: curLevy, name: curName };
      },
      { levy: 0, name: 0 }
    );
    
    return [[levyLine], [nameLine]];
    
  }, [data]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  if (!data || isLoading) return "Loading...";

  return (
    <ResponsiveLine
      data={view === "levy" ? levyLine : nameLine}
      theme={{
        axis: {
          domain: {
            line: {
              stroke: theme.palette.secondary[200],
            },
          },
          legend: {
            text: {
              fill: theme.palette.secondary[200],
            },
          },
          ticks: {
            line: {
              stroke: theme.palette.secondary[200],
              strokeWidth: 1,
            },
            text: {
              fill: theme.palette.secondary[200],
            },
          },
        },
        legends: {
          text: {
            fill: theme.palette.secondary[200],
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          container: {
            color: theme.palette.primary.main,
          },
        },
      }}
      margin={{ top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 70 }}
      xScale={{ type: "point" }}
      yScale={{
        type: "linear",
        min: "auto",
        max: "auto",
        stacked: false,
        reverse: false,
      }}
      yFormat=" >-.2f"
      curve="catmullRom"
      enableArea={isDashboard}
      axisTop={null}
      axisRight={null}
      axisBottom={{
        format: (v) => {
          if (isDashboard) return v.slice(0, 3);
          return v;
        },
        orient: "bottom",
        tickSize: 5,
        tickPadding: 5,
        tickRotation: 0,
        legend: isDashboard ? "" : "Quarter",
        legendOffset: 36,
        legendPosition: "middle",
      }}
      axisLeft={{
        orient: "left",
        tickValues: 5,
        tickSize: 5,
        tickPadding: 5,
        tickRotation: 0,
        legend: isDashboard
          ? ""
          : `Total ${view === "sales" ? "Revenue" : "Units"} for Year`,
        legendOffset: -60,
        legendPosition: "middle",
      }}
      enableGridX={false}
      enableGridY={false}
      pointSize={10}
      pointColor={{ theme: "background" }}
      pointBorderWidth={2}
      pointBorderColor={{ from: "serieColor" }}
      pointLabelYOffset={-12}
      useMesh={true}
      legends={
        !isDashboard
          ? [
              {
                anchor: "bottom-right",
                direction: "column",
                justify: false,
                translateX: 30,
                translateY: -40,
                itemsSpacing: 0,
                itemDirection: "left-to-right",
                itemWidth: 80,
                itemHeight: 20,
                itemOpacity: 0.75,
                symbolSize: 12,
                symbolShape: "circle",
                symbolBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
                effects: [
                  {
                    on: "hover",
                    style: {
                      itemBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
                      itemOpacity: 1,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            ]
          : undefined
      }
    />
  );
};

export default LevyChart;
```

This is the LevyDataSet that is working on MongoDB

```
export const levyDataSet = [
    {
     year: "2017/2018",
     quarters: [
      {
       name: "Q1",
       levy: 387549
      },
      {
       name: "Q2",
       levy: 589445
      },
      {
       name: "Q3",
       levy: 603971
      },
      {
       name: "Q4",
       levy: 609281
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     year: "2018/2019",
     quarters: [
      {
       name: "Q1",
       levy: 617934
      },
      {
       name: "Q2",
       levy: 639593
      },
      {
       name: "Q3",
       levy: 640304
      },
      {
       name: "Q4",
       levy: 650134
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     year: "2019/2020",
     quarters: [
      {
       name: "Q1",
       levy: 675816
      },
      {
       name: "Q2",
       levy: 674741
      },
      {
       name: "Q3",
       levy: 764173
      },
      {
       name: "Q4",
       levy: 767220
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     year: "2020/2021",
     quarters: [
      {
       name: "Q1",
       levy: 818587
      },
      {
       name: "Q2",
       levy: 835825
      },
      {
       name: "Q3",
       levy: 861072
      },
      {
       name: "Q4",
       levy: 878795
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     year: "2021/2022",
     quarters: [
      {
       name: "Q1",
       levy: 880184
      },
      {
       name: "Q2",
       levy: 864827
      },
      {
       name: "Q3",
       levy: 928235
      },
      {
       name: "Q4",
       levy: 911216
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     year: "2022/2023",
     quarters: [
      {
       name: "Q1",
       levy: 925677
      },
      {
       name: "Q2",
       levy: 920331
      },
      {
       name: "Q3",
       levy: 1014663
      },
      {
       name: "Q4",
       levy: 1000
      }
     ]
    }
   ];
```

I've added the stack trace for those asking. Thank you.

```
ERROR
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:395:12
    at updateMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:124873:23)
    at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:125449:20)
    at useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145462:25)
    at LevyChart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:379:78)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:124084:22)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:126966:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:128678:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:113676:18)
```

I've tried for hours searching, tinkering. Even used chatgpt lol. Nothing! It's probably something dumb. This is supposed to take my data and render it out to a chart using Nivo Line.

I've tried making sure the data is not null and that the data is being called correctly in the console, which is it. I've played around with the keys to try and make it work. I'm at a loss right now. I've added the stack trace for those asking. Thank you.

This is the stack trace for TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

````
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68521:89
    at mountMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:124856:23)
    at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:125241:20)
    at useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145462:25)
    at be (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68520:57)
    at Ge (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68994:12)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:124084:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:127370:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:128666:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:113676:18) ```
````

Comment: are you able to share the stack trace?

Comment: @RobertRendell I've added the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates there's an issue with this:

```
   Object.values(quarters).reduce(...)
```

Here's a
[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PIIwVgpgxgLgdANwIYBsCuEDOAKNA7AEwgDMBLPCAgAiUxrwE8BKAbgCgB6DqgYSTzwB7GFSiC8CCACcR+ImQrVBUqnjQoUVGIKqDw0EWzahIsRKgw41GmnX7N2XXvyEixE6bMIlylXSutNbV19WCo2IA) demonstrating that if `quarters` is `null` or `undefined` then you will get that error (`Cannot convert undefined or null to object`).

To solve this issue you need this line:

```
if (!quarters) return [];
```

Here it is in context:

```
const [levyLine, nameLine] = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return [];

    const { quarters } = data;
    const levyLine = {
      id: "levy",
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      data: [],
    };
    const nameLine = {
      id: "name",
      color: theme.palette.secondary[600],
      data: [],
    };

    if (!quarters) return [];
    console.log("quarters", quarters);
    Object.values(quarters).reduce(
      (acc, { year, name, levy }) => {
        const curLevy = acc.levy + levy;
        const curName = acc.name + name;
    
        levyLine.data = [
          ...levyLine.data,
          { x: year, y: curLevy },
        ];
        nameLine.data = [
          ...nameLine.data,
          { x: year, y: curName },
        ];
    
        return { levy: curLevy, name: curName };
      },
      { levy: 0, name: 0 }
    );
    
    return [[levyLine], [nameLine]];
    
  }, [data]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Comment: I added that as you suggested and now I get a different error. ``` TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') ```

Comment: The code that you shared doesn't call `filter` anywhere, sounds like your original question has been answered and you've made progress to your next error.

Comment: I know, and I haven't called it anywhere else either which is why I'm now scratching my head even harder. I'll accept your answer anyway though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use the latest stack trace to pin down the root of the error and if you aren't calling filter anywhere, maybe it's being called by one of the script dependencies: `import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { useGetLevyQuery } from "../state/api";`

Comment: Starting with @nivo/line, I checked its documentation and code, and it does use the filter method, but it is not used in the ResponsiveLine component. Therefore, it is unlikely that this dependency is causing the error.

Comment: Moving on to @mui/material, the useTheme hook does not use the filter method, so this dependency is also unlikely to be causing the error.

Comment: And filter is definitely not called in "../state/api"

Comment: post the next stack trace

Comment: I added the stack trace. Thanks